# Error (upon exe of post-install script) deploying Angular CLI app to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, angular-cli

I am trying to deploy a simple Angular CLI app (via Git) to Heroku. I followed the instructions on this excellent site to do so: 
https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-cli-deployment-host-your-angular-2-app-on-heroku-3f266f13f352#.nqa94v6g1

I got these Heroku post-install script running errors concerning the out-of-the box Angular CLI testing functionality. What's going on? NOTE: that I have just discovered this occurs even when the npm postinstall script is run locally, it's not a Heroku prob.

```
ERROR in Cannot determine the module for class RouterLinkStubDirective in /tmp/build_a6cc5f65bc82b6c7a75e181d83d9be96/src/app/testing/router-stubs.ts!
remote:        Cannot determine the module for class RouterOutletStubComponent in /tmp/build_a6cc5f65bc82b6c7a75e181d83d9be96/src/app/testing/router-stubs.ts!
remote:        
remote:        ERROR in ./src/main.ts
remote:        Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/tmp/build_a6cc5f65bc82b6c7a75e181d83d9be96/src'
remote:        @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
remote:        @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

Answer (score 1):

Oops, I thought this was out-of-box test functionality for the Angular-CLI but it was actually what I migrated across accidentally from the project I was porting into the CLI. Once removed, it is fully deployable to Heroku. Sorry to waste your time!